# Binding data from request to select input - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a get request which fetches data from my database. I want to populate this data into my select box. But when i populate my select box, it shows there are elements in the box but the name doesn't appear. The elements(data) drop down but no text shows.. What am i doing wrong below?

What could i be doing wrong in there?

```
fetchData(){
        return this.fetchPost().then(([response,json]) => {
           console.log(response);
           if(response.status === 200)
           {
              console.log(response);
              console.log(json.data);
              this.setState({
                 itemsAvailable: json.data.items
              })
           }
        })
     }

render() {

        let items = this.state.itemsAvailable;
        let optionItems = items.map((myItem) =>
             <option key={item.name}>{item.name}</option>
           );

        return (
         <FormGroup style={select}>
             <Select
                options={optionItems}                           
             /> 
        </FormGroup>
       );
}
```

Comment: It has to do with how you're trying to render the `option` without its required attribute e.t. `value`. So the value is what the `select` will give along with the `onChange` event. And inside the tag is just what you want to be displayed!

Comment: Read more here https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag